# Application.EnableVisualStyles() not working

Tags: c#

I cann't make my application to apply Windows visual styles.
Application.EnableVisualStyles() in program.cs not changing RenderWithVisualStyle property to true.

```
 [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] startArgument)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            .....

        }
```

Interestingly if I'm debugging with "Enable visual studio hosting process", Application.EnableVisualStyles() works as expected, RenderWithVisualStyle goes to true and styles are applied. But no styles without hosting process either Debug or Release mode.
Changing target framework v.2 to v.3.5 makes nothing.

Any ideas please, I'm stuck with this issue and googling for 3 days with no success.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed a manifest XML file that specifies that the new version of the common controls DLL should be used.  See [the MSDN article on visual styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289524%28VS.71%29.aspx#vbtchusingwindowsxpvisualstyleswithcontrolsonwindowsformsanchor3) for more information on how to do this.

Comment: That's not how it is done in Windows Forms, CreateActCtx() is the key.

Comment: I cannot speak for that mechanism, but using manifest files is exactly the approach Microsoft documents for enabling visual styles on C# Winforms applications.  It has worked for me in the past when I've used it.

Comment: I've tried manifest, that doesn't help. Manifest seems to be an old solution used in .NET Framework v.1.1 mostly.

Comment: Ah, hmm, I must have missed that memo.  :)